# Why do I get told my questions should be Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)

Yesterday, [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323704/what-computer-science-concept-do-you-apply-the-most) that was subjective but really helpful to me. There was no right answer. The question was eventually closed, but I did get some good information out of it.

One of the initial complaints (which has been removed it seems) was that my question should have been a wiki post.  The tag was "should-be-wiki" someone added.  A search for "wiki" on here turns up several references to the "Community Wiki", but I can't figure out where this beast is. The FAQ doesn't mention it. I can't find any links or even a guideline for when a question belongs here nor there?

I asked what seemed like an applicable question which produced some good information, but I got yelled at for doing it. Furthermore, I don't see any obvious path for me to follow to have done this the "right way".

Comment: Should be wiki!

Comment: Don't wiki this question.

Comment: *Welllllllbog*

Comment: What? Joke's too *deep* for you, Ian?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740

Comment: @Lance: Still pulling that old trick? WTF?

Comment: @Shog9: Don't worry, reported to the mods. Please do the same, not worth arguing with trolls and their behavior.

Comment: I missed the excitement :(

Comment: At least I got my cleanup badge out of Lance's edit.

Comment: Why did Diago take the CW tag off this post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Community Wiki checkbox is to the bottom right of the text area where you enter your question. However keep in mind just because its CW doesn't mean you can ask whatever you want, it still has to follow the proper rules for posting a question.

Answer (score 6):

You need to stop posting these kinds of questions. Period.

"was subjective" ... "There was no right answer."

This is in direct opposition to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> What kind of questions should I not
>   ask here?
>
> Avoid asking questions that are
>   subjective, argumentative, or require
>   extended discussion. This is not a
>   discussion board, this is a place for
>   questions that can be answered!

Answer (score 5):

Here you go: [What are “Community Wiki” posts on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1):

Community Wiki does get a *very brief* mention in the FAQ:

> 100    Vote down (costs 1 rep), edit community wiki posts

Perhaps this should link to the item Shog9 points out?

And there is a link to the detailed FAQ at the bottom of the main FAQ:

> **What about...**
>     If you're looking for excruciating detail, we host a section of constantly evolving FAQs that document everything about the site.